# fill in the data NaN with the data that is above it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with the data below :
ii want filling NaN in the data with the data on above data.

```
   a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   NaN NaN 4
4   NaN NaN 5
```

I want to push the data to NaN to make it look like this :

```
    a   b   c
0   NaN NaN 1
1   NaN NaN 2
2   1   1   3
3   2   2   4
4   3   3   5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a null values mask, then concatenate the non-null and null rows:

```py
>>> nullMask = df.isnull().sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
>>> pd.concat([df[nullMask], df[~nullMask]])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    a   b   c
1           
4   NaN NaN 4
5   NaN NaN 5
2   1.0 1.0 1
2   2.0 2.0 2
3   3.0 3.0 3
```

Since, you don't want the values in non-null columns i.e. `c` in the sample data to be reordered, you need two maskings: one for columns to know which columns have null values, and one for indices in-order to shift the null values in the columns to the begining:

```py
nullCols = df.isna().sum()
nullCols = nullCols[nullCols.gt(0)].index.tolist() 
nullMask=df[cols].isnull().sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
out=pd.concat([df[nullCols][nullMask], df[nullCols][~nullMask]], ignore_index=True)
remainingCols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(nullCols)].tolist()
out[remainingCols] = df[remainingCols].values
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    a   b   c
0   NaN NaN 1
1   NaN NaN 2
2   1.0 1.0 3
3   2.0 2.0 4
4   3.0 3.0 5
```

Comment: in column c there is a change in how to make the position as it was at the beginning ?

Comment: You just want to shift the values not the entire row?

Comment: Yes, i don't want to change it

Comment: Okay, I'll update the answer, but doing so, you'll loose your data integrity.

Comment: Also update the question with correct data, right now, there are two rows with index value `2` in the sample data but that's not the case for expected result.